# GNS representation associated with faithful weight is faithful

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

I'm reading Takesaki's second volume and I have a question:

Let $M\subseteq B(H)$ be a von Neumann algebra and let $\varphi: M_+ \to [0, \infty]$ a weight. We assume moreover that $\varphi$ is semifinite, which is defined as follows by Takesaki (p41):

> The weight $\varphi$ is called-semifinite if $\mathfrak{p}_\varphi=\{x \in M_+: \varphi(x) <\infty\}$ generates $M$.

**Question 1**: What exactly does this mean? Is this generated as a von Neumann algebra? As a linear space? It feels natural to require that we first consider the $*$-algebra generated by $\mathfrak{p}_\varphi$ and we require density of this $*$-algebra in either of the weak/strong/strong$^*$-topologies or their $\sigma$-counterparts (the closures in all these topologies automatically coincide).

---

With respect to the weight $\varphi$, we can consider a GNS-construction. I'll briefly sketch how this can be done.

Basically, the first thing we do is consider
$$\mathfrak{n}_\varphi = \{x \in M: \varphi(x^*x)< \infty\}$$
which is a left ideal of $M$. Then we consider the subspace $N_\varphi = \{x \in M: \varphi(x^*x) = 0\}$ and the quotient vector space $\mathfrak{n}_\varphi/N_\varphi$ becomes an inner product space for
$$\langle x + N_\varphi, y + N_\varphi\rangle := \varphi(y^*x)$$
where the right hand side makes sense because we can define $\varphi$ on elements
of the $*$-subalgebra
$$\mathfrak{m}_\varphi = \mathfrak{n}_\varphi^*\mathfrak{n}_\varphi$$
in a way that agrees with how $\varphi$ is defined on $\mathfrak{p}_\varphi$. Then $H_\varphi$ is the Hilbert space completion of this quotient space and we have a unique $*$-representation $\pi_\varphi: M \to B(H_\varphi)$ uniquely given by
$$\pi_\varphi(x): H_\varphi \to H_\varphi: y + N_\varphi \mapsto xy + N_\varphi.$$

Takesaki now claims that if $\varphi$ is faithful and semi-finite (and also normal, but I don't think this matters here), then $\pi_\varphi$ is also faithful.

**Question 2**: Why is this the case? If $\pi_\varphi(x)=0$ for some positive (without loss of generality, by the $C^*$-identity) $x \in M$, then
$$0=\langle \pi_\varphi(x)(y+ N_\varphi), z+ N_\varphi\rangle = \varphi(z^*xy)$$
for all $z,y \in \mathfrak{n}_\varphi$.

In particular, if $z \in \mathfrak{p}_\varphi$, we get
$$0 = \varphi(z^{1/2} x z^{1/2}) = \varphi((z^{1/2}x^{1/2})(z^{1/2}x^{1/2})^*)$$
so faithfulness of $\varphi$ gives $z^{1/2}x^{1/2}=0$. Hence, $zx=0$ for all $z \in p_\varphi$. Now, I guess to conclude I will have to know the answer to question $(1)$!

Comment: For Q1 it must be generated as a von Neuman algebra because the set that appears in the definition is already a linear space. It seems similar to the idea for densely defined unbounded operators on a Hilbert space where it is required that there is a domain for the operator which is dense in the Hilbert space.

Comment: @ShannonStarr $\mathfrak{p}_\varphi$ is not a linear space. It is not closed under scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, *semifinite* means that $\mathfrak m_\varphi$ is $\sigma$-weak-dense (i.e. wot-dense, sot-dense, etc.).

Once you know that $zx=0$ for all $z\in p_\varphi$, you also get that $z^*z=x=0$, so $zx=0$ for all $z\in \mathfrak n_\varphi$. Similarly you also get that $zx=0$ for all $z\in\mathfrak m_\varphi$. As $\mathfrak m_\varphi$ is dense in $M$, you are done.

Comment: Elements in $\mathfrak{m}_\varphi$ are sums of elements in $\mathfrak{p}_\varphi$, so we can even finish faster :)

Comment: Linear combinations, but yes.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In Bratteli and Robinson volume 1 (2nd edition) on page 146 in Definition 2.7.12, it says that a weight is called semifinite if:

$\mathfrak{M}_{\omega}$ is $\sigma$-weakly dense in $\mathfrak{M}$.

I think this argues that your guess is right: it means it generates it in the topology of the weak-$*$ algebra.

Comment: Thank you! On a side note, is this reference you mention interesting to check out?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that for the community of people working on quantum spin systems from the mathematical perspective, it is. The mathematician who imparted the importance of Bratteli and Robinson to me was Bruno Nachtergaele, and he is the one who I think of when I think of mathematicians who use Bratteli and Robinson. Its title is "Operator Algebras and Quantum Statistical Mechanics 1."

Comment: Hmmm, on hindsight I'm not sure if this is correct. Note that $\mathfrak{p}_\varphi$ consists of positive elements, and a $\sigma$-weak limit of positive elements is again positive (because this is also a weak limit), so in the $\sigma$-weak closure we only find positive elements! So the question remains: should we take the linear span and then close or the $*$-algebra generated and then close.

Comment: Yes I think there are some details a bit different, but the end product is probably the same. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Sorry I deleted my old comment because I made a mistake.